# when trying to compile my code this shows up (ld returned 1 exit status)

Tags: c, gcc

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Temp\ccHsyq5r.o:myMath.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `computeMax'; C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Temp\ccw8OyKh.o:main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Temp\ccHsyq5r.o:myMath.c:(.text+0x4a): multiple definition of `ComputeMin'; C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Temp\ccw8OyKh.o:main.c:(.text+0x4a): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Temp\ccHsyq5r.o:myMath.c:(.text+0x94): multiple definition of `computeMean'; C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Temp\ccw8OyKh.o:main.c:(.text+0x94): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Saurabh\AppData\Local\Temp\ccw8OyKh.o:main.c:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `computeMin'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

No idea what this is can someone guide me would really appreciate it

Comment: You have multiple definitions of some functions. Could be also the case where you didn't clean up the old object files before a new build.

Comment: Cleaniup your upper/lower cases. For C compiler "computeMin" is not the same as "ComputeMin". That is for fourth error. This is to make your post more readable, https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help , please format your error quotes as code with triple `\``. Add a [mre] of the code files you have. All of them. You would not by any bad luck be including code files anywhere? I ask because your first three errors could be explained by two code files being compiled and linked and main.c including myMath.c.

Comment: hey mate ive looked around my whole program and all my functions have the same definitions no idea what is happening it cant use other files to run so why is telling me there is another definition in a temp file?